# How to solve this equation involving an absolute term in sympy?

Tags: sympy, equation-solving

```py
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x', real=True)

solve(Abs(2 + 36/(x - 2)) - 6)
```

I've already set `real=True`, but it still says `solving Abs(2 + 36/(x - 2)) when the argument is not real or imaginary.`

However, solving `Abs(36/(x - 2)) - 6` is fine.

What's the problem?

Comment: I consider this a bug. It should be reported to github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: Issue open: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/23480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, dealing with `Abs` leads to "suprise" moments, like you experienced. For your particular case, a possible way to make it works is to manipulate the expression. In particular, make `abs(x / y) = abs(x) / abs(y)`:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x', real=True)
expr = Abs(2 + 36/(x - 2)) - 6
expr = expr.simplify()

def repl_Abs(t):
    num, den = fraction(t)
    return Abs(num) / Abs(den)

solve(expr.replace(Abs, repl_Abs))
# out: [-5/2, 11]
```

Comment: Solve should be able to do this if the symbol is real.

Comment: I agree! It's better to open an issue on SymPy.